# Code won't run on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile

I had written a simple Pomodoro-timer in code pen. This runs both on laptop and on mobile perfectly.I can't post the link to code pen without unnecessarily including code snippets? so the link to my code pen project is

My code was very repetitive and just bad, so I successfully re wrote it using objects and cut the code in half. Here is the GitHub project

This version works perfectly on my laptop, however will not run on mobile. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: Update your mobile... Works perfectly on mine...

Comment: Wich app? Newest chrome does work...

Comment: Chrome as well.. weird

Comment: You know that data is cached, so your js may be cached when you opened it while it was unfinished...